# Docker container only accepting requests from local network

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have been trying my best to learn Docker lately and have come accross an issue I have never had before and can't find anyone online with the same issue. My webserver is only accessible from machines in the same network as my server.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu server. On this there is a single docker container running a nginx server. The container is created using a docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./client
      network: host
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node AS build

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /client

# Copy files
COPY . .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Build frontend
RUN npm run build

# Nginx
FROM nginx
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build client/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

nginx.conf:

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-domain.be www.my-domain.be;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

My domain name points to my public IP and the server is configured as a DMZ at the router. When loading the web-page on a machine that is on the same network as my server everything works as expected, but when it is loaded from a machine outside the network the server doesn't respond.

The nginx logs show that the GET-request never arrives. This is because the TCP handshake from the client is never acknowledged. (I found this through `tcpdump`)

I know the problem lies with docker because I have configured nginx on the Raspberry Pi directly and everything works as expected. The problem probably lies in dockers internal networking, which I have absolutly no experience with. If you would need any extra info to solve the problem, please let me know!

Comment: Docker's networking layer doesn't know anything about "local network" vs. not.  If you have `ports: "80:80"` it should be indistinguishable from a host process listening on 0.0.0.0:80.

Comment: That is exactly what I read online, but the error seems to lie with Docker since the same configuration wothout Docker on the same machine works perfectly fine.